# Perl: How to pipe output of an open command to a file

Tags: perl

I want to run a program and pipe its output to a file. The program could run for several hours, so i want to log all the data that happens while the program is running. How would i do it?

So in perl i have done this so far. As an example, i'm using ifconfig as my program. So in this case i want to output the ifconfig to a file. But the below code is outputting to STDOUT. How do i redirect the output to a text file?

```
my $program1 = "/sbin/ifconfig";
open my $print_to_file, "|-", $program1, @args;
print $print_to_file;
close($print_to_file);
```

Comment: Do you have some reason for doing this in perl? Just running it from the shell and redirecting the output to a file would be simpler. Using perl is overkill unless you plan to do something with the data you are reading (other than just putting it into a file).

Comment: Yea, i will have to do lot of processing with the data. ifconfig was just an example. The program might run for hours and i need to do processing from the logs i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `$print_to_file` is an input handle (it is the output stream of the external program, but your Perl script reads from it). So read from it and write its contents to a file through an output filehandle:

```
open my $read_from_cmd, "|-", $program1, @args;   # an input handle
open my $print_to_file, '>', $the_file;           # an output handle
print $print_to_file <$read_from_cmd>;
close $read_from_cmd;
close $print_to_file;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
`$program @args > outfile`
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? open my $print_to_file, "|-", $program1, @args > outfile;

Comment: No. Why do you need the $print_to_file? If you are only running the command and not sending data to it (e.g ifconfig) then my solution with nothing else should work.